# How to understand recursion for binary representation function

Tags: python, recursion

I traced the following code, and one part doesn't make sense to me:

```
def bin_rep(n: int) -> str:
     """Return the binary representation of n
     >>> bin_rep(0)
     "0"
     >>> bin_rep(1)
     "1"
     >>> bin_rep(5)
     "101"
     """

     if n > 1:
         return bin_rep(n // 2) + bin_rep(n % 2)
     else:
         return str(n)
```

The part that I don't understand is, why are we adding `bin_rep(n//2)` and `bin_rep(n%2)`. I know that without the addition this won't work, but I can't wrap my head around why the addition exists there.

Comment: Since `bin_rep` always returns a string, this is a string concatenation rather than an addition. Does that help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bin_rep(n)` returns the binary string representation of `n`.

The termination condition is `n <= 1` which is `bin_rep(0) -> '0'` or `bin_rep(1) -> '1'`.

`bin_rep(2)` must return `'10'`.  To do that it computes:

```
bin_rep(2 // 2) + bin_rep(n % 2)
bin_rep(1) + bin_rep(0)
'1' + '0'  # String concatenation, not decimal addition!
'10'
```

... which is the correct answer.  That should help clear up your understanding.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped me out a lot!

Answer (score 4):

That's not addition.  `bin_rep` returns a string.  The `+` operator for type string is concatenation.  Read this as

```
binary representation of n right-shifted a bit
    concatenated with
binary representation of n's right-most bit
```

Does that clear it up?